# Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, rxjs5, rxjs6

I am trying to upgrade to Angular 6 from 5 and got this error:

> ERROR in src/app/services/http.service.ts(17,14): error TS2339:
>   Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

My code in http.service.ts:

```
import { throwError as observableThrowError,  Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from "environments/environment";
import { AppService } from 'app/app.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    private baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private appService: AppService) { }

    public get(endpoint: string): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + endpoint)
            .timeout(this.appService.timeoutInterval)
            .retryWhen(error => error.delay(this.appService.waitInterval)
                .take(this.appService.numberOfRetries)
                .concat(observableThrowError(new Error())))
            .share();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've made some changes to my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be updating with ng update - see https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4 (scroll down a little)

As per this link, this will auto install `rxjs-compat` which will enable support for RxJs v5 and v6

You could however install `rxjs-compat` manually if you want.

This will ease the transition for ng5 to ng6 and then (optionally) pull it out later in a more RxJs focused task.

Comment: Only problem was that rxjs-compat wasn't installed automatically which your answer made me realize

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to add a `.pipe` and then use any of your operators within it since Rxjs 6.

Change your implementation like this:

```
import { throwError ,  Observable, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from "environments/environment";
import { AppService } from 'app/app.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { 
  timeout,
  retryWhen,
  take,
  concat,
  share,
  delayWhen
} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  private baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    private appService: AppService
  ) {}

  public get(endpoint: string): Observable < any > {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + endpoint)
      .pipe(
        timeout(2500),
        retryWhen(errors =>
          errors.pipe(
            delayWhen(val => timer(val * 1000))
          )
        ),
        take(2),
        concat(throwError('This is an error!')),
        share()
      );
  }
}
```

**PS:** I took the liberty to change your `AppService.` references with my own implementation as you didn't share your `AppService` code.

Answer (score 1):

Now instead of `timeout` you should use `debounceTime`.
For example, [from official doc](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6):

```
this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
    );
```

Comment: And how do I implement retryWhen and share using this pipe?

Comment: you can use retryWhen operator from rxjs 6

Comment: i've never used retryWhen, try looking at ere https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2018/06/21/retry-failed-http-calls-in-angular-6/

Answer (score 1):

you must execute the command

```
npm install rxjs-compat
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining it a bit, eg. why do you think that is the missing part, or why is that step needed.